# Call and extract name of an excel sheet using the index of sheet in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, xlsread

We can call a sheet using it's name or index by `xlsread` function like this:

```
    for i=1:100
      file = xlsread(`filename.xlsx`,i)
      %% I want get name of the called sheet here (storing in cell array)
    end
```

In this loop if want call and extract the specified sheet name (using the index of sheet) as we can see in comment line of above loop and store the names in a cell array. How can I do this in MATLAB R2015a?

Comment: [`xlsfinfo`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsfinfo.html) has a sheet name output.

Comment: @excaza . thank you. please add your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [`xlsfinfo`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsfinfo.html), which has an optional `sheets` output that returns a cell array of the sheet names. For example:

```
xlswrite('test.xlsx', 1:3, 'hi');
xlswrite('test.xlsx', 1:3, 'hello');
xlswrite('test.xlsx', 1:3, 'hey');

[~, sheets] = xlsfinfo('text.xlsx');
```

Returns:

```
sheets = 

    'Sheet1'    'hi'    'hello'    'hey'
```

Note that `Sheet1` is only present because I generated a blank spreadsheet. If a sheet name specified in the `xlswrite` call is not present in the target sheet it is added to the end of the workbook.

EDIT: ActiveX implementation:

```
eAX = actxserver('Excel.Application');
mywb = eAX.Workbooks.Open('C:\test.xlsx');
mysheets = eAX.sheets;
numsheets = mysheets.Count;

sheets = cell(1, numsheets);
for ii = 1:numsheets
    sheets{ii} = eAX.Worksheets.Item(ii).Name;
end

mywb.Close(false)
eAX.Quit
```